# script to populate monthly summary tables based on the date field in one table

Tags: sql, groovy, plsql

I need to develop an sql script like a pl/sql block to populate records into monthly transaction tables like txn_jan, txn_feb...txn_dec from a single usertransaction table. this table has a currentdate field which I can parse to get the month and then summarize all similar transaction by incrmenting the count of transaction_cnt field in each monthly table (if other fields are all same - resourceid, userid, objectid). So if a user has done samekind of transactions repeatedly in a day then usertransaction table will have seperate entries for each trnasaction, but monthly summary tables will have a count of the transaction with only the date part in its date field (summarize on time in a date).

How do I go about developing the script for populating the summary tables..I have the usertransaction table populated with data.

> **usertransaction table fields**: userid, resourceid, doc_name, transid,
>   currentdate (includes time)
>
> **monthly summary table fields**: userid, resourceid, doc_name, transid,
>   currentdate (excludes time), trans_count

I can do this using java or groovy too ..but i thought plsql might be best?

Comment: ergh - homegrown partitioning... have you considered having just one summary table, with a "Month" column?

Comment: I thought about that, the problem is that when I port this implementation to MySQL the queries run really slow even with indexes so we took this approach..but may be we can consider this approach when we want more type of date to be summarized, using the same summary tables..

Comment: @pri_dev : "when I port this implementation to MySQL"... is this for Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: both...and may be for more db types...hence dont want to run on the power of oracle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do two things here. I assume you're using Oracle (seeing as you're using Java).

First, you want to group up each user's daily transaction.
Create a staging table called `tempTable`.
Use `to_char(currentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')` to group them up.

```
INSERT INTO tempTable
SELECT 
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  trans_id,
  to_char(currentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as currentday,
  to_char(currentdate, 'MM') as month_value,
  count(*) as daily_count
FROM 
  usertransaction 
GROUP BY 
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  trans_id,
  to_char(currentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

if you have too many rows of data, I recommend that you do this instead; do it once per day.

```
INSERT INTO tempTable
SELECT 
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  to_char(currentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as currentday,
  to_char(currentdate, 'MM') as month_value,
  count(*) as daily_count
FROM 
  usertransaction 
WHERE
  to_char(currentdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') = to_char(SYSDATE, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
GROUP BY 
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  trans_id
```

---

Second, you will want to do multiple inserts according to `month_value`.

```
INSERT INTO txn_jan
SELECT
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  to_date(current_day, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as current_day,
  daily_count
FROM
  tempTable
WHERE month_value='01'

INSERT INTO txn_feb
SELECT
  userid,
  resourceid,
  doc_name,
  to_date(current_day, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as current_day,
  daily_count
FROM
  tempTable
WHERE month_value='02'
```

and continue on..

Comment: hey... thanks a lot! you got all assumptions right :) ...its very close to the reqd solution..only thing remains is I need to check values of userid, resourceid, docname should be same..there should be a separate entry in summary table if any of these values is not same.. right now the daily_count is irrespective of values of these fields.. like total daily count.. what it should be is like daily_similar_transaction_count..

Comment: `right now the daily_count is irrespective of values of these fields` <-- maybe its because I have added new stuff when you're reading the old text.

Comment: suppose usertransaction 2 entries are (transid, userid,resourceid,docname,date) (2,1,3,design.doc, 1/18/2012 19:35:26..) and (2,3126,3,design.doc, 1/18/2012 21:35:26..) ...i.e 2 different users on same doc at different times... these would be summarized with the above logic right?... I need these to be in 2 different rows in the summary table...

Comment: ohh i see the group by clauses...sorry missed that..!

Comment: @pri_dev yes. the relevant code is in the `GROUP BY` in the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you're after:

```
INSERT INTO txn_jan
SELECT userid, resourceid, doc_name, transid,
    cast(currentdate as date) as currentdate,
    count(*) as trans_count
FROM usertransaction
WHERE extract(year from currentdate) = 2012
    and extract(month from currentdate) = 1
GROUP BY cast(currentdate as date)
```

Comment: thanks for the the start..I would say I need to run this in a loop over for populating all 12 months.. also how about comparing the other fields like userid, resourceid, doc_name, transid.. only rows which have same values for these should be selected right?

Comment: or rather if the values of the other fields are same only then they should be counted and then grouped on date..

Comment: I see, I misread the question. In that case, there'd be no `over()` after the `count(*)` and you would group by the date. In PostgreSQL you can do `GROUP BY cast(currentdate as date)`. Not sure if it's the same in Oracle or (another detail I missed, sorry). I updated my answer.